# How to find trusted certificate for both Android and iOS?

Tags: android, ios, certificate, truststore

*disclaimer* it is self Q&A question

Several times I faced with situation when our customers bought a certificate considered as "trusted" on iOS, but unfortunately on Android it didn't work.

What is the cause and how to solve it?

Comment: This is true, SO is not a blog post service but it's aim to help find answers on the questions. This a business value of this platform. I believe this post fits the format of SO and bring value to users who are looking for the answer for their issue

Comment: I think we put a different meaning in the goal of SO, this is why we are facing the difficulty to find agreement. As a welcome page says "With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming." Till criteria 'Q&A about programming' are met, all posts are welcome. SO have short answers, detailed answer and even wiki -- service doesn't limit us in ways to answers questions. Perhaps, it would be better to find real question like that but I had tried and didn't find, that's why I create my own as I had this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is buy common trusted certificate.

The reasons is trust store on Android devices contains different set of trusted certificates -- IOS and Android trusted certificates are different.

It can be described on sets:
A -- android trusted certificates
I -- iOS trusted certificates
AI -- intersection of trusted certificates

Therefore, we need an intersection of those two platforms.

However, this issue becomes more complicated because set of trusted certificates varys by OS version for both Android and iOS. It means we will need to look through all supported platforms and all their supported versions to find common set of supported certificates.

For iOS the list of trusted certificates are available on their official site [list of supported iOS certificates](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204132)

For Android I don't find the same list but it is possible to get it from runtime by code below.

```
 public List<CertificateDto> getCertificates() {
        List<CertificateDto> result = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            String algorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
            TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
            trustManagerFactory.init((KeyStore) null);

            X509TrustManager xtm = (X509TrustManager) trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers()[0];
            for (X509Certificate cert : xtm.getAcceptedIssuers()) {
                PublicKey publicKey = cert.getPublicKey();
                int leyLength = 0;
                if (publicKey instanceof RSAPublicKey) {
                    leyLength = ((RSAPublicKey) publicKey).getModulus().bitLength();
                } else if (publicKey instanceof DSAPublicKey) {
                    leyLength = ((DSAPublicKey) publicKey).getY().bitLength();
                }

                CertNameToValidNameConverter validNameConverter = new CertNameToValidNameConverter();

                CertificateDto certificate = new CertificateDto();
                certificate.setSubjectName(validNameConverter.convert(cert.getSubjectDN().getName()));
                certificate.setIssuerName(validNameConverter.convert(cert.getIssuerDN().getName()));
                certificate.setKeyLength(leyLength);
                certificate.setTypeAlg(cert.getSigAlgName());
                certificate.setExpirationDate(cert.getNotAfter().getTime());

                result.add(certificate);
            }
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            Log.e(App.TAG, "Failed obtain list of certificates", e);
        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            Log.e(App.TAG, "Failed obtain list of certificates", e);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

When you get the list of certificates from your supported Android OS, you will need to write script to look through all certificates and compare it with another list from different supported Android version and after that with iOS versions as well. You will need compare certificate name, issuer name, algorithm type, sign algorithm and length of the key. Expiration date is also used for validation but you can omit it.

I implemented this script by parsing certificates from excel for **IOS 8,9** and **Android 6.0, 4.4 and 4.1.**

The final list of certificates you can find below. From ~220 IOS certificates and ~150 certificates you can use only ~65 certificates for both platform

[list of supported certificates for both Android and iOS (google drive link)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OwwAaJjgCHHQJY9whRJc5_BiHVeKfshP4UcMJfuXTIo/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Also don't forget Microsoft and that the list of trusted certificates changes over time. Also be aware of the certificate level, some platforms will only search up a few levels and if the root is not reached the certificate will be rejected. But the answer is to buy certificates from top line providers.

Comment: Thank you! it is valuable comment. I didn;t find the list of Microsoft certificates. It would be great if you can provide the source and I add comparation with them as well. p.s. and this list of certs are top level